# WebBrowser Script Error On DashBoard Pages Blogger.com

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, browser, blogger

A Client hired me about a week ago to create a webbrowser on a vb.net application with some basic functions(More like a macro which could help with his Blog activities). However I somehow discovered that there is an impossible error to fix when I'm trying to browse the Google http://Blogger.com/home dashboard page even when I'm logged in on a gmail account, there's a really annoying error coming up `(Script Error)` saying this

> object doesn't support property or method 'getcomputedstyle'

Has anyone maybe the solution to this error? It's really important to get this fixed as soon as possible as I'm on a deadline and this whole Blogger thing could be a deal-breaker.

I should probably mention that I tried disabling Script Errors from IE Options but that didn't help.

I also found a JS code with a possible fix to my problem but the title was probably missleading and it didn't help me at all.

And I even gave a shot to Microsoft solution about a giving the webbrowser a TrueValue, but after taking each step and running the app I realized that neither did that work..

Lastly I added this code

```
WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```

and that just hides the error from appearing but the page still remains blank without my VB application crashing.

I took a screenshot of the Script Error in case it's more helpful than me talking about it. Please offer me any possible solution you have in mind!

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and running my PC on Windows 8.

[image: http://s9.postimg.org/det2x5jdr/prntscrn.png]

**EDIT:** I still haven't found any solution to my problem. However I tried visiting the same link on my IE to check if the browser has indeed the problem and after logging in with an account, an error pops up with this code: **bX-wnrswi**

Those type of errors as I read appear only on IE so I'm still not sure where exactly to look and what to do in order to avoid this freakin error. If you feel that you can help me with your advice then feel free and do it! I'm desperate..

**2nd EDIT:** I forgot to mention that I actually have installed Windows 8.1 instead of 8. Windows 8.1 came pre-installed with IE11 which is their brand new version and surprise-surprise is full of bugs. I'm almost certain that this version of IE is the root of my problem. However on Windows 8.1 it's almost impossible to downgrade from IE 11 to IE 10 or just uninstall IE 11 and install an older version. However I'm searching about it, if anybody feels like he has a solution please post about it.

**RESOLVED - FIXED:** Finally after spending almost 6h trying to solve this worthless pie** of s*** I found a way to fix it. After trying almost everything (It's 2AM in the morning atm) before abandoning this I thought I should give it one last try. So I just changed my project settings from run on any CPU to my PC, so x64 and I finally got passed this stupid issue.

In case anyone else has this problem, here's the solution:

On your VB toolbar, click the drop-down arrow -> Customize -> Enable Toolbar (or Menu Bar) -> Select Build -> Add Command -> Add "Configuration Manager...(If not visible left click on your Toolbar and enable The Configuration Manager) -> Compile to whatever system you got, x32 or x64 instead of Any CPU.

Comment: The Webbrowser control in VB is just a (sometimes buggy) wrapper around an IE window and will actually be influenced by the installed version of IE. Note that your fix probably means you're invoking the 64-bit version of IE with all the associated issues. Btw you can also get to the Build Config just by right-clicking the solution in solution explorer. Finally, if you've answered your question, please post the solution as an answer and accept it so others (like me) don't come and read the whole thing before realising you don't need help any more. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can control which version of IE the Webbrowser control uses by executing program.
See http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version

Answer (score 0):

On your VB toolbar, click the drop-down arrow -> Customize -> Enable Toolbar (or Menu Bar) -> Select Build -> Add Command -> Add "Configuration Manager
This worked for me
[thewindowssolution.com](http://thewindowssolution.com/)